# How can I update the value of my variable

Tags: python, database, flask, web-applications, sqlalchemy

I am new to Flask and databases, and I am having trouble changing the value of carbs as I want to input a custom value on my web app online. I am having difficulties understanding why it's not changing because I have used the same form technique to change the value of my content variable and it is successful in changing it. And also the submit button does not do anything when clicked.

This is how it looks like, the add carb button does not respond to any action:

[image]

```
content = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
proteins = db.Column(db.Integer,default = 0)
carbs = db.Column(db.Integer,default = 0)
fats = db.Column(db.Integer,default = 0

@app.route("/carbs", methods = ['GET','POST'])    
def carbs():
    if request.method =='POST':
        carb_add = request.form1['quantity']
        carb_data = Data(carbs = carb_add)
        try:
            db.session.add(carb_data)
            db.session.commit()
            return carb_data
        except:
            return "Issue with the entry"    
    else:
        checkcarb = Data.query.order_by(Data.date_created).all()
        return render_template('home.html',checkcarb = checkcarb)
```

```html
<form1 action="/carbs" method = "POST">
  <input type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity">
  <input type="submit">
</form1>
```

Answer (score 0):

`request.form1['quantity']` is a string, while your db requires an integer.  Try:

`carb_add = int(request.form1['quantity'])`

**Update:**

This:

```
<form1 action="/" method = "POST">
```

POSTs the form to the root level of your app.  You are not showing your url handlers here, but I'd bet the root does not go to the `carbs()` function.

Try this:

```
<form1 action="" method = "POST">
```

or:

```
<form1 action="/carbs" method = "POST">
```

Comment: i tried doing that it still did not work. And also when I click on the button for the form1 on html it does not do anything.

Comment: See the Update I just posted

Comment: I tried this as well, its not responding.  @app.route("/carbs", methods = ['GET','POST']
def carbs():
    rand = random.randint(0,100)
    if request.method =='POST':
        carb_add = request.form1['add_carbs']
        carb_data = Data(carbs = carb_add)
        
        try:
            db.session.add(carb_data)
            db.session.commit()
            return redirect('/')
        except:  The HTML is this: <form1 action="/carbs" method = "POST">
        <input type="number" id="content" name="add_carbs">
        <input type="submit" value="Add Carbs">
    </form1>

Comment: Can you update your question with this code, so we can see it better?

Comment: Also, `request.form1['add_carbs']` comes over as a string, so try `int(request.form1['add_carbs'])`

Comment: i did it did not work.it uses the default and displays it. What I did was i added a random number to default value for it to display. but I really want it to display what i type in the form.